# ios ViewModel with ReactiveCocoa v3 and Swift 1.2

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, reactive-cocoa-3

I'm having trouble using ReactiveCocoa in version 3. I want to build some view model for my login view controller. In my view controller I have outlet for password text field:

```
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
```

In view model I have property for the text that is the password

```
public let emailText = MutableProperty<String>("")
```

and the question is how to bind it together? I'm able to get SignalProducer from text field:

```
emailTextField.rac_textSignal().toSignalProducer()
```

but how to bind it to emailText property? I've read in documentation that SignalProducer is *not* a Signal, but it can create now. There is method start() but it takes Sink as parameter and I'm a bit confused with design at this moment. Shouldn't emailText be a Sink?

Answer (score 0):

Note: this is not properly an answer to your question, but I think it might help you.

If you are just want to bind your view to your view model, I suggest you to read [this post](http://rasic.info/bindings-generics-swift-and-mvvm/) which provides a one-class solution to the problem.

From there, you can very simply implement a 2-way binding so your viewmodel get updated every time the view changes and vice-versa. Here is my extension:

```
class TwoWayDynamic<T> {
    typealias Listener = T -> Void
    private var viewListener: Listener?
    private var controllerListener: Listener?
    private(set) var value: T

    func setValueFromController(value: T) {
        self.value = value
        viewListener?(value)
    }

    func setValueFromView(value: T) {
        self.value = value
        controllerListener?(value)
    }

    func setValue(value: T) {
        self.value = value
        controllerListener?(value)
        viewListener?(value)
    }

    init(_ v: T) {
        value = v
    }

    func bindView(listener: Listener?) {
        self.viewListener = listener
    }

    func bindController(listener: Listener?) {
        self.controllerListener = listener
    }

    func bindViewAndFire(listener: Listener?) {
        self.viewListener = listener
        listener?(value)
    }

    func bindControllerAndFire(listener: Listener?) {
        self.controllerListener = listener
        listener?(value)
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!